# How to put array into file using for loop in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, concatenation, fstream, fwrite

I have declared 3 arrays where each element in `parent` array is the name of the parent, and `dollah` and `mamat` array consist of name of their children.

```
ofstream WFile;
string parent[]={"dollah","mamat"};
string dollah[]={"aniza","azman","azilawati"};
string mamat[]={"mad","rushdi","roslan"};
```

I want to make a `FOR loop` that can be used to put the name of the children in their own `family` file.

```
for (int i=0; i<14;i++){
    len= cout<<(sizeof(parent[i))/cout<<sizeof((parent[i])[0]);

    WFile.open("Family"+i+".txt");
    if(WFile.is_open()){
    cout<<"File opened"<<endl;
    for(int j=0;j<len;j++){
        WFile<<(parent[i])[j]<<endl;    
        }
    }else{
        cout<<"File cannot opened"<<endl;
    }
    WFile.close();
}
```

The error shows

> [Error] invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [5]' to binary 'operator+'

Comment: Why do you calculate the length of the strings the way you do? Why not just use `parent[i].length()`? Not to mention that the calculation you do won't even work as the size of a `std::string` object is not equal to the length of the string.

Comment: how should I approach this problem because currently, the file just write the parent's name. Not the children's name.

Comment: That calculation you do is actually worse than I initially saw. What you're doing is essentially `len = cout / cout;`. Not to mention that you have a syntax error in the code you show. When creating a [mcve] to show us, please make sure it replicates the problem you ask about, and nothing more. Then copy-paste it *as-is* into the question, don't rewrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literal strings are really arrays of constant characters, and as such will decay to pointers (i.e. `char const*`).

You try to add an integer to a pointer, and then add another pointer to the result. That makes no sense.

Use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert the integer to a `std::string` and it should work:

```
"Family"+std::to_string(i)+".txt"
```